# Sort list of dict based on value present in another list in python

Tags: python

I have following list of dict:

```
list_of_dict = [
{'vectorName': 'draw', 'value': 52.06}, 
{'vectorName': 'c_percentage', 'value': 15.24}, 
{'vectorName': 'o_temprature', 'value': 1578.0}
]
```

I have another list of keywords:

```
list_of_keywords = ['draw', 'o_temprature', 'name', 'c_percentage', 'data']
```

I want to sort the list of dict based on list of keywords and then get list of values in ordered format :

```
[512.06, 1578.0, 15.24]
```

I am trying following peice of code but not working (getting list_of_sorted_dict as `None`).

```
list_of_sorted_dict = list_of_dict.sort(key=lambda x: list_of_keywords.index(x["vectorName"]))
```

Kindly help

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error? Unexpected result?

Comment: If you are expecting list_of_sorted_dict to be the ordered list, the .sort built-in method returns None and rather change the list in place. After the operation list_of_dict should more or less be the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but the [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) is an in-place sorting method, which means that it sorts `list_of_dict` and returns `None`. If you want a separate sorted variable, you can do the following.

```
list_of_sorted_dict = sorted(list_of_dict, key=lambda x: list_of_keywords.index(x["vectorName"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use two fors to achieve that

```
    list_of_dict = [
{'vectorName': 'draw', 'value': 52.06}, 
{'vectorName': 'c_percentage', 'value': 15.24},
{'vectorName': 'o_temprature', 'value': 1578.0},
]

list_of_keywords = ['draw', 'o_temprature', 'name', 'c_percentage', 'data']

list_of_sorted_dict = []

for key in list_of_keywords:
    for item in list_of_dict:
        if(item['vectorName'] == key):
            list_of_sorted_dict.append(item)   

print (list_of_sorted_dict)
```

result :

[{'vectorName': 'draw', 'value': 52.06}, {'vectorName': 'o_temprature', 'value': 1578.0}, {'vectorName': 'c_percentage', 'value': 15.24}]